# When I add xsd file with xml I cannot access xsl file

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xsd

I have a xml file, I can access the data with xsl file. But when I add xsd to my xml file, I cannot use my xsl file. Please help me

```
<updateClient 
   xsi:schemaLocation=" file://updateClient.xsd"
   xmlns="http://" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <fileHeader>
    <messageType version="100">
        <recordTp>722</recordTp>
    </messageType>
    <sendingCompany>some</sendingCompany>
    <processDate>2018-02-13</processDate>
    <recordCount>10</recordCount>
     </fileHeader>
    </updateClient>
```

My XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:x="http://localhost" exclude-result-prefixes="x" >
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
      <body>
     <h2>My Collection</h2>
      < table>

          <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="updateClient/fileHeader/messageType">
           <td> <p>RecordType :<xsl:value-of select="recordTp" /></p> </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>


        </table>
     </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
       </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your input XML is located in the `http://` namespace. Your XPath expressions in the XSL file have no namespace prefix, so they are looking for elements in the default namespace.

If you can use XPath 2.0, you can use the ´ xpath-default=namespace´ attribute, i.e.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://" ...>
```

In XPath 1.0 you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ns1:updateClient/ns1:fileHeader/ns1:messageType" xmlns:ns1="http://">
```

Or, you could remove the namespace declaration in your input XML and use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://updateClient.xsd"` instead of `xsi:schemaLocation`.